# Unable to build pybind11 example when using cmake due to undefined references

Tags: c++, cmake, pybind11

I can not build the example for pybind11 due to undefined references to the python headers such as "undefined reference to `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize'"

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h> does not cause problems, but this does:

```
int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m){
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

I think I added the python library correctly, so idk:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(sps LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework serialization REQUIRED)
find_package (Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(extern/pybind11)

add_library(
    sps
    INTERFACE
    src/probtree.h
    src/node.h
    )
target_link_libraries(sps INTERFACE Boost::serialization)
target_include_directories(sps INTERFACE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(sps INTERFACE extern/pybind11/include)

set_target_properties(sps
    PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 20
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    )

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main sps)

pybind11_add_module(
    sps_c

    src/probtree.h
    src/node.h
    src/main.cpp
    )
set_target_properties(sps_c PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(sps_c INTERFACE sps)

add_executable(test_sps test/test_sps.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_sps Boost::unit_test_framework sps)
```

I was getting these undefined references before, but `find_package (Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)` and `target_include_directories(sps INTERFACE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})` fixed it.

I thought linking the pybind11 module would work `target_link_libraries(sps_c INTERFACE sps)` but no.
How do I fix the undefined references?

Answer (score 0):

`target_link_libraries(sps INTERFACE Boost::serialization ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})` needed to be added for the python definitions to be found.